# Find a substring from a column and write into new column (Multiple column search)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a newbie to the PYSPARK.

I am reading the data from a table and updating the same table. I have a requirement where I have to search for a small string in to columns and if found I need to write that into new column.

Logic is like this:

```
IF 
(Terminal_Region is not NULL & Terminal_Region contains "WC") OR
(Terminal_Footprint is not NULL & Terminal_Footprint contains "WC")
THEN REGION = "EOR"
ELSE
REGION ="WOR"
```

If both of those fields has NULL, then REGION = 'NotMapped'

I need to create a new REGION in the Datafarme using PYSPARK. Can somebody help me?

```
|Terminal_Region    |Terminal_footprint |   REGION |
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
|  west street WC   |                   |     EOR  |
| WC 87650          |                   |     EOR  |
| BOULVEVARD WC     |                   |     EOR  |
|                   |                   |Not Mapped|
|                   |landinf dr WC      |     EOR  |
|                   |FOX VALLEY WC 76543|     EOR  |
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked when I imported the 'pyspark.sql' from import functions.

Comment: You are welcome. and feel free to mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code should create your desired output. The code should work with spark 2.2, which includes the `contains` function.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df =  spark.createDataFrame([("west street WC",None),\
                      ("WC 87650",None),\
                      ("BOULVEVARD WC",None),\
                      (None,None),\
                      (None,"landinf dr WC"),\
                      (None,"FOX VALLEY WC 76543")],\
                      ["Terminal_Region","Terminal_footprint"]) #Creating Dataframe
df.show() #print initial df
df.withColumn("REGION", when( col("Terminal_Region").isNull() & col("Terminal_footprint").isNull(), "NotMapped").\  #check if both are Null
otherwise(when((col("Terminal_Region").contains("WC")) | ( col("Terminal_footprint").contains("WC")), "EOR").otherwise("WOR"))).show() #otherwise search for "WC"
```

Output:

```python
#initial dataframe
+---------------+-------------------+
|Terminal_Region| Terminal_footprint|
+---------------+-------------------+
| west street WC|               null|
|       WC 87650|               null|
|  BOULVEVARD WC|               null|
|           null|               null|
|           null|      landinf dr WC|
|           null|FOX VALLEY WC 76543|
+---------------+-------------------+
# df with the logic applied
+---------------+-------------------+---------+
|Terminal_Region| Terminal_footprint|   REGION|
+---------------+-------------------+---------+
| west street WC|               null|      EOR|
|       WC 87650|               null|      EOR|
|  BOULVEVARD WC|               null|      EOR|
|           null|               null|NotMapped|
|           null|      landinf dr WC|      EOR|
|           null|FOX VALLEY WC 76543|      EOR|
+---------------+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks you so much for the code. When I did this, I am getting the following error. "NameError: global name 'when' is not defined"

Comment: Did you include the functions import `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`? Because `when` is usually part of those. Then it should work.